# C/C++ multithreading - run threads sequentially, sorted based on a particular variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I am running a multithreaded application in C++. The number of threads is variable and each thread has it's own set of variables, parsed from a JSON type command line argument. I have to run these threads sequentially (may defeat the purpose of multithreading, but need to keep it this way for other use cases) based on the variables in descending order.

Say for example, the command line arg is something like:

```
{"ID":[1,4,3,2]}
```

I have to start a thread corresponding to each ID sorted in descending order [4,3,2,1]. Starting from ID=4; after thread corresponding to ID=4 finishes, I have to run a thread for ID=3, after this finishes, run thread for ID=2 and then thread for ID=1.

What would be a good design for this problem?

Comment: What parallel runtime are you using?

Comment: Why not simply use one single thread, and just do actions "4", "3", "2" and "1" in that order in your thread? Otherwise there's really no need to use threads.

Comment: Yep, definitely sounds like a use case for a single thread processing a queue of jobs

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/7bzzjWcf5 you can try latches/barriers if you're on C++20. This is by no means production ready, rather a quick&dirty example for demonstation only, but adding all the needed boiler plate should be relatively easy.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So, the use case is such that this thread that processes sequentially should run parallelly with other threads.

Comment: Use a thread for that, not a problem. But the sequential stuff, just do it sequentially, no need to bother with threads for that.

Comment: For what seems to be your use-case, use a thread-pool. Read the file line by line (or using whatever parsing is needed to get the data). For all the "lines" that should be worked on in parallel ask the tread-pool to work with it. If the pool have no available threads, wait until there are (perhaps a work-queue could handle it automatically). Then each thread parses the "line" to get the work it need to do, sort the work in your preferred order, and do them in that order one by one in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic solution without using any C++20 features, one drawback is that your thread functions must be of a specific type, none/void-returning with no parameters in this case, but you could extend this class to support functions of arbitrary parameters.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class ThreadScheduler {
public:
    using ThreadFunction = void(*)();
    vector<pair<int, ThreadFunction>> m_threads;
public:
    void add_thread(int id, ThreadFunction f) {
        m_threads.emplace_back(id, f);
    }

    template <class Compare>
    void run_seq(Compare comp) {
        using PairRef = reference_wrapper<pair<int, ThreadFunction>>;       
        vector<PairRef> temp_threads(m_threads.begin(), m_threads.end());
        
        sort(
            temp_threads.begin(), temp_threads.end(),
            [&](PairRef p1, PairRef p2) {
                return comp(p1.get().first, p2.get().first);
            }
        );

        for (auto& t : temp_threads) {
            t.get().second();
        }
    }

    void run_parallel() {
        vector<thread> thread_handles;

        for (auto& t : m_threads) {
            thread_handles.emplace_back(t.second);
        }
        for (auto& th : thread_handles) {
            th.join();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    ThreadScheduler ts;

    ts.add_thread(4, []() {
        cout << "4\n";
    });
    ts.add_thread(12, []() {
        cout << "12\n";
    });
    ts.add_thread(2, []() {
        cout << "2\n";
    });
    ts.add_thread(8, []() {
        cout << "8\n";
    });

    ts.run_seq(greater<int>());
    ts.run_parallel();

    return 0;
}
```